# Perl: how to find items between any same two arbitrary regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl, match, words

I am trying to find and extract texts between any 2 identical but arbitrary key words. For example, given the string:

```
"aa bb aa cc 11 dd bb 11 cc"
```

...I want to get:

```
"aa bb aa"

"bb aa cc 11 dd bb"

"cc 11 dd bb 11 cc"

"11 dd bb 11"
```

When I do `m/(\w+).+?($1)/`, or when I use look-ahead operator, nothing seems to work and can't find all of it.

Comment: How exactly did you invoke the regex? `echo "11 dd bb 11" | perl -ne '/(\w+).+?($1)/; print $1'` works for me.

Comment: Not sure why those answers were downvoted. They both look like they work to me.

Comment: echo "11 dd bb 11" | perl -lne 'if ($_ =~ m/(\w+)(.+?)($1)/) { print "$1 $2 $3\n"; }'  well, this only gives me "11" and nothing else.

Comment: echo "11 dd bb 11" | perl -lne 'if ($_ =~ m/(\w+)(.+?)($1)/) { print "$1 $2 $3\n"; }'  well, this only gives me "11" and nothing else. Thank you all for your help. Comments above and below are greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: echo "11 dd bb 11" | perl -lne 'if ($_ =~ m/(\w+)(.+?)(\1)/) { print "$1 $2 $3\n"; }' works

Answer (score 2):

Three problems:

- You're using `$1`, but within the regex backreferences use a backslash, not a dollar sign: `\1`.
- You're trying to match whole words, but your regex lacks word boundaries.
- You say you've tried lookaheads, but you don't say how.

The regex you want is:

```
(?=((\b\w+\b).+?(\b\2\b)))
```

You also need to add the `/g` flag and do the matching in a `while` loop to get all the results:

```
my $subject = "aa bb aa cc 11 dd bb 11 cc";
while ($subject =~ m/(?=((\b\w+\b).+?(\b\2\b)))/g) {
    print "$1\n"
}
```

The matches will `$1` because the whole match occurs inside a lookahead, meaning `$&` will be empty.

Here's a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW7mT6/1) (Regex101.com),
and a [code demo](http://ideone.com/AiBDdz) (Ideone.com)

Comment: echo "aa bb aa cc 11 dd bb 11 cc" | perl -lne 'if ($_ =~ m/(?=((\b\w+\b).+?(\b\2\b)))/g) { print "$1 -- $2 -- $3\n"; }' will give you aa bb aa -- aa -- aa

Comment: @lisprogtor. if you change the `if` to `while`, you'll get all four of the results you're looking for.  I've added a Perl example to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a non-regex solution to this. The program below does what is required

It first splits the string into items and stores them in array `@items`. Hash `%indexes` is a hash relating each different item to the indexes in `@items` where it appears, and array `@keys` is the keys of the hash in the order they appear in `@terms`. (There's no need for this if the order of the output is immaterial.)

The subsets of the `@terms` array are printed for each value of `%indexes` that has two or more items. `while` is used with `splice` in case there is an item that appears four or more times, in which case the output will consist of the first appearance to the second, the third to the fourth etc. If this isn't required then the program can be simplified further

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $str = "aa bb aa cc 11 dd bb 11 cc";;
my @items = split ' ', $str;
my ( %indexes, @keys);

for my $i ( 0 .. $#items ) {
    my $key = $items[$i];
    push @keys, $key unless $indexes{$key};
    push @{ $indexes{$key} }, $i;
}

for my $key ( @keys ) {
    my @indexes = @{ $indexes{$key} };
    while ( @indexes >= 2 ) {
        my ( $beg, $end ) = splice @indexes, 0, 2;
        print "@items[$beg .. $end]\n";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
aa bb aa
bb aa cc 11 dd bb
cc 11 dd bb 11 cc
11 dd bb 11
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right you can use `(?{ code })` pattern and `(*FAIL)`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'aa bb aa cc 11 dd bb 11 cc';
$s =~ /((\b\w+\b).*\2)(?{print "$&\n"})(*FAIL)/g
```

Result seems to be as you expected:

```
$ perl test.pl
aa bb aa
bb aa cc 11 dd bb
cc 11 dd bb 11 cc
11 dd bb 11
```

Comment: (?{ code }) means this is perl6, right? I am getting to perl6. How solidified is perl6, or how much of perl6 has been finalized?

Comment: It's perl5. This feature is old enough - [exists even in 5.8.8](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlre.html). By the way backtracking control verb `(*FAIL)` added in [Perl 5.10.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/perl5100delta.html)